# Why is indexing a html collection results to null or undefined compared to just outputting an html collection

Tags: javascript, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am writing a browser extension using the usual way with manifestv3 and scripts in content.js. I am searching for specific divs of a website for injecting contents, but indexing an html collection doesn't return any. I need to be able to atleast select a specific div by class.

Here is the code in content.js

```
DocumentAccountInfo=document.getElementsByClassName("some_class_name");
console.log(DocumentAccountInfo);//outputs a complete html collection
console.log(DocumentAccountInfo[0]);//outputs undefined
console.log(DocumentAccountInfo.item(0));//outputs null
```

I tried to enclose it in a function to wait for the DOM to load, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Perhaps there are no elements with the class name on the page. What does `console.log(DocumentAccountInfo.length)` print to the console?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule .length prints 0

Comment: If the divs you are searching are generated after some time and you can't know how much, you can use setInterval to continously check, then clearInterval to stop the loop when you find them. Also check your getElementsByClassName in the console to see if it returns anything when the divs are surely there

Comment: A selector method returns `null` value when there is no element/node available to be returned instead.

Comment: to put more context, I am trying to find a specific div of a twitter account page. I want to manipulate this `<div class="css-1dbjc4n r-6gpygo r-14gqq1x">`, thus this is the actual `document.getElementsByClassName("css-1dbjc4n r-6gpygo r-14gqq1x")` . @Ankit Using the querySelectorAll(".css-1dbjc4n.r-6gpygo.r-14gqq1x") returns 0

Comment: Hello @das, have you found a solution to your problem? I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
let DocumentAccountInfo=document.querySelectorAll(".app");
console.log(DocumentAccountInfo);
console.log(DocumentAccountInfo[0]);
console.log(DocumentAccountInfo.item(3));
```

```html
<div class="app">11</div>
    <div class="app">12</div>
    <div class="app">13</div>
    <div class="app">14</div>
```